# Huge problem to display decision tree in Jupyter Notebook in Python: ExecutableNotFound?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, display

I have a problem to create and display decision tree in Jupyter Notebook using Python. 
My code is as below:

```
X = data.drop(["Risk"], axis=1)
y = data["Risk"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
klasyfikator = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", random_state=0, max_depth=4, min_samples_leaf=1)
klasyfikator.fit(X = X, y = y)


data = export_graphviz(klasyfikator,out_file=None,feature_names=X.columns,class_names=["0", "1"],   
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)
graph = graphviz.Source(data)
graph
```

Generally this decision tree concerns credit risk research 0 - will not pay 1 - will pay.

When I use code above, I have error like this:

> ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

I have already tried many solutions from StackOverflow, for example:

1. pip install graphviz
2. Conta install graphiz
3. I Downloaded Graphviz from http://www.graphviz.org/download/
4. I added to the PATH environment variable:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin

And there is still error described above. What can I do? what should I do ? Please help me guys because I'm losing hope of being able to draw this tree. Thank you!

Moreover, when I added by using this code:

```
import os 
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'
```

I have in PATH something like this: `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\x08in` it is not the same, what can I do ?

Comment: `import os` and check `os.environ['path']` in your current session. If you changed your path environment variable while jupyter notebook was already running then you may need to relaunch jupyter to get most up-to-date environment variables

Comment: how can I add this paths to the environment variable ? and should I both these paths: C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin and C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe ?

Comment: You just need to add up to “.../bin/“, not the actual exe itself. Check https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10/949577#949577 or https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: look when I added by using this code: import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin' I haave in PATH something like this: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\x08in' it is not the same, What can I do ?

Comment: It’s the “\b” that’s tripping you, that’s a special char in python. Use double “\\” or put an ‘r’ in front of the graphviz path: r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\'

Comment: Ok  your tip works but I still can not display decision tree, I still have error: ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Comment: Maybe just update path the old fashioned way https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/amp/ and remember to close and relaunch jupyter

Comment: Should I add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to PATH both to system and user environment or onlny in 1 ? if only 1, so which ?

Comment: Add to system...

Comment: I do not believe it still does not work, I added to the system PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin   and I still have error: ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

With latest version of sklearn, you can directly plot the decision tree without `graphviz`.

Use:

```
from sklearn.tree import plot_tree

plot_tree(klasyfikator)
```

Read more [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html).